# Disable cache option in developer tools doesn't work

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I check disable cache when dev tools is open but my firefox still caching some javascript. Cmd + Shift + R doesn't affect this behavior. Some files like font are cleared but javascript files seems to still cached for some of them.

When I go to preferences and manually clear the cache it's work. But it's not really efficient.

Also using Web Developer Toolbar to disable cache is working.
**Edit :** Worked just for times and after a reboot of my laptop it's stop working.

Any Idea someone ?

Comment: Have you tried it in Firefox stable version? Does it work when you uncheck and check it?

Comment: Can you try on a non-e10s build?

Comment: I'm too having this issue (tried on Firefox Developer Edition). The option is use-less, the cache is not disabled.

Comment: Also having this issue.
Ubuntu 15.04, latest stable Firefox (41.0.1 for now).
Web developer toolbar works for me too.

Comment: I think you should report this as bug @ [Bugzilla@Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Updating plugins solved this issue for me.

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/